# How do you remove the space in a C# string?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
String test = "John, Jane";

test.Replace(" ","");

String[] toList = test.Split(',', ' ', ';');
```

How would you remove just the space in the string or any space that shows up potentially?

Why is there 3 items in array and not 2?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To remove any space, just replace it with any empty string:

```
test = test.Replace(" ", "");
```

Note that *just* calling `string.Replace` won't do it - strings are immutable, so the *return value* of `string.Replace` is a reference to a new string with the relevant replacements.

Comment: @rod: Given the mistake in the code shown in the question, do you still need any help?

Answer (score 5):

It's as simple as:

```
test=test.Replace(" ","");
```

If you want any whitespace to be removed you'll need a [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Regex r=new Regex("\\s+");
test=r.Replace(test,"");
```

**Re:** Why is there 3 items in array and not 2?

Because you're splitting by *both* comma and space (split arg 1+2) because there's both a comma and a space between `John` and `Jane` you're getting:

```
["John", "", "Jane"] // (in JSON notation ;))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
        string test2 = test.Replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer to the question posed is the same as all listed above:

```
test = test.Replace(" ", "");
```

However, since this is the first result in search engine, and the answer for a related question of removing spaces from the start/end of a string is:

```
test = test.Trim();
```

I figure I might as well mention this so others can benefit...if they scroll down this far.

And visually why 3 parts not 2: if I insert pipes around each split character, you can see there is "John" before the first split, back-to-back split characters in the middle yielding an "extra" empty part, then "Jane" after the last split.

```
"John|,| |Jane"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all types of whitespace, you can use `string noWhiteSpace = Regex.Replace("John, Jane", @"\s", string.Empty);`  If you just want to remove the space character, use `string noSpace = "John, Jane".Replace(" ",string.Empty);`

Just saw the second part to your question you added in your edit:

You get three items in your array because your test string will split at each token contained in your list of characters to split at.  Your string contains both a space and a comma, and you get a split at the comma, and a split at the space.

If you don't want the empty entries, you can use the following:

```
String[] toList = test.Split(new char[] {',', ' ', ';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Of course, if you have the whitespace removed, then you won't have any spaces to split at.

Answer (score 0):

So the full solution would be this:

```
String test = "John, Jane";

test = test.Replace(" ","");

String[] toList = test.Split(',', ';');
```

> Why is there 3 items in array and not 2?

For 2 reasons: 1) when you call `Replace` you are generating a **new** string, and you need to store it in some variable - the original string is *immutable*. 2) Then you were using a space (`' '`) as one of separators when calling `Split`; you don´t need that (you are removing all spaces in the previous line).